# "Might be" vs. "Perhaps"

Tags: word-usage, grammar, vocabulary, word-difference, spoken-english

How to use "Might be" and "Perhaps"? Are these terms interchangeable in a sentence?

Although I use dictionaries for references, I still face difficulties when *forming sentences* with these two words. I especially *can't decide* in what types of sentences, I should use these ones.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, they are essentially interchangeable in meaning, but not in grammatical construction. "Perhaps" is a bit more formal, and would sound weird in a causal conversation, and "might be" is a little casual for an essay.

However, you couldn't just *find and replace* "might be" with "perhaps" or vice versa.

"I might be going to the play this weekend", or "I might go to the play this weekend" means the same as "Perhaps I will go to the play this weekend."